# How to iterate over ActiveRecord relation through a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

So i've got certain IceCream in which i'd like to get the sales amount in Ontario of low fat ice cream and non expired, say.

IceCream has_many ontario_sales_receipts:

```
included_ice_cream = IceCream.produced_this_or_previous_month.where(low_fat: true, expired: false)

final_amount = included_ice_cream.ontario_sales_receipts.pluck(:number_of_buckets).sum * BUCKET_PRICE
```

But this results in:

```
undefined method `ontario_sales_receipts' for #<IceCream::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0055de80e3ffa8>
```

How do I make available a has_many association from an ActiveRecord relation?

I could originally query OntarioSaleRecept, but I don't know how to query them based on their has_one association with specific IceCream

```
included_ontario_sales_receipts = OntarioSalesReceipt.where( their associated IceCream is lowfat and non expired ... )
```

Comment: try `final_amount = included_ice_cream.collect{|iic| iic.ontario_sales_receipts.pluck(:number_of_buckets) }` it's because the method `#ontario_sales_receipts` is a method on an instance of IceCream, not a collection (AR Relation)

Comment: It is unclear how `OntarioSalesReceipt` is related to `IceCream` but inference suggests that `IceCream.joins(:ontario_sales_reciepts).produced_this_or_previous_month.where(low_fat: true, expired: false).sum(:number_of_buckets) * BUCKET_PRICE` should work.

Comment: I appreciate that, both. @LesNightingill, that gave me an array of arrays, which I summed, giving me an array, which I summed, giving me the correct number of buckets, which I could then perform the rest of the calculations. engineerksmnky, that got it it thank you, first time seeing both collect and joins, will research both now

Answer (score 0):

```
included_ice_cream = IceCream.produced_this_or_previous_month.where(
      low_fat: true,
      expired: false
    )
    total_amount = final_amount(included_ice_cream)

    def final_amount(included_ice_cream)
      included_ice_cream.map do |ice_cream|
        ice_cream.ontario_sales_receipts.pluck(:number_of_buckets).sum *
          BUCKET_PRICE
      end.sum
    end
```

how about this?